# Идеальное выравнивание (SSE SIMD)

Tags: c++, c

Как можно сделать идеальное выравнивание ?  К примеру

```
 int AlignA = (int)Source & 15; // = 4
 int AlignB = (int)Dest & 15; // = 3
```

Что бы Source  и Dest выровнялись до X & 15 == 0 и можно было конечный результат проверить потом

Пишу свой Move с использованием SSE. По этому задался таким вопросом.

Вот код который получился на данный момент 
https://github.com/NyaSik/TestNove/blob/master/MoveSSE.c

```
 int AlignSS = (int)Source & 15;
    if(AlignSS == ((int)dest & 15)) {
        if(AlignSS) {
            AlignSS = 16 - AlignSS;
            switch(AlignSS)  {
                MoveSSE(16 * 0 + 1, 0, 1, dest, Source);
            }
            dest += AlignSS;
            Source += AlignSS;
            len -= AlignSS;
        }
        MoveLen(dest, Source, len, 1);
     } else {
         MoveLen(dest, Source, len, 0);
 }
```

Comment: 1. Что вы имеете в виду под идеальным выравниванием? 2. Вы уверены, что округлив вниз вы не заденете в память выделенную другим переменным?

Comment: 1. Именно  - то, что бы выравнять данные A и B ровно, для _mm_store_si128 что бы не использовать _mm_storeu_si128 когда блок данных не 16 байт (Именно этот блок и выровнять до следующих 16 байт, в A и Б) ........... 2. Пока не предусмотрены были защиты такие, так как их легко добавить